# Learning roadmap from Euclidean geometry to Projective geometry

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, self-learning, book-recommendation, projective-geometry

As we know that Euclidean geometry deals with triangles, quadrilateral,... and circles. Later in college we learn projective geometry but in quite modern language (vector spaces, equivalent relations).

My question is, is there any roadmap or any book to learn projective geometry from high school Euclidean geometry which would be easier for high school student to learn projective geometry.

I think it would be really helpful if our student could have some intuition with projective geometry before learning sth more modern like algebraic geometry.

Comment: I'm sympathetic to your question - projective geometry is a beautiful topic that was much more central to the curriculum 150 years ago.  But what part of the current high school math curriculum would you eliminate to make room for even a brief excursion into projective geometry?

Comment: It's quite certain that there's little room for student to learn projective geometry in class, however, they could read its material in math circle or math clubs, I think. It would be very helpful for them to learn projective geometry in the language of the usual stuffs in Euclidean geometry.

Comment: I found a very good source for your comment here, the reason why synthetic projective geometry doesn't appear in undergraduate programs also. https://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/2974060.pdf